# Unknown RPC service:

Tags: share

I'm trying to integrate g+ share button on my website. 
If I place it on static part of page, everything works fine. But if I place it on modal it does not open, and I am getting messages in console:
Unknown RPC service: onVisibilityChanged rs=AItRSTPg3AKJNQb-mFQlUvzu84VKqzUF-g:106
Unknown RPC service: _onopen rs=AItRSTPg3AKJNQb-mFQlUvzu84VKqzUF-g:106
Unknown RPC service: _ready rs=AItRSTPg3AKJNQb-mFQlUvzu84VKqzUF-g:106

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because I was generating g+ share button with jquery, after all javascript was loaded.
I solved the problem by defining hidden div and inside it g+ share button, and just showing that div with jquery.